# Is this a helpfull optimization for loops in java?

Tags: java, android, optimization

consider the following :

1.

```
    for (final Bar a : bars) {
        for (final Foo f : foos) {
            doSomethingWith(f.foo(), a.bar());
        }
    }
```

and :

2.

```
    for (final Bar a : bars) {
        final Object bar = a.bar();
        for (final Foo f : foos) {
            doSomethingWith(f.foo(), bar);
        }
    }
```

Is this kind of optimization really helpfull or will the compiler do it automatically anyway?

Will your answer change if bar() was a getter? (e.g getBar())

Will your answer change if i am targeting Android development?

Comment: Work for the student: compile both versions and compare the bytecode output.  Here is a reference; https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html

Comment: Well i dont think that this question is a student level question but oh well I was wondering if anyone already knows the answer to that rather than telling me that it is possible to look at the output bytecode, which i know i could. and also, i would have to look at the outputs for android as well. this can be one hell of a project to answer this question on my own.

Comment: Can the compiler know that `a.bar()` will always return the same value for a given `a`?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy of course it can not

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy it depends how deep it gets into a.bar() code, if at all, maybe in a multi-threading eviroment such as in java, it cannot predict a.bar() would always return the same value even if the code is as simple as return bar;

Comment: @BobMalooga no its not, notice that bar is called inside the foos loop

Comment: You have an perfect opportunity to test. Add some time varables and start mesuring if you don't want to start counting O -operations.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried two examples as per you doing for your question. On this basis I must say Second Approach would be better. (**Although I am not considering Multi-Threading**)

> Test.java

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String... args){

        String[][] arr2 = new String[5][5]; 
        for (final String[] obj : arr2)
        {
            for (final String str : obj)
            System.out.println(str.length() +" " + obj.length); 
        }
    }
}
```

after compiling and then again decompiling I got this.

```
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_114.
 */
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Test {
    public static /* varargs */ void main(String ... arrstring) {
        String[][] arrstring2;
        String[][] arrstring3 = arrstring2 = new String[5][5];
        int n = arrstring3.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            String[] arrstring4;
            for (String string : arrstring4 = arrstring3[i]) { //assignment will take place m*n.
                System.out.println("" + string.length() + " " + arrstring4.length);
             //this arrstring4.length will execute m*n (in this case).So, this will less efficient than others.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Test1.java

```
public class Test1{

    public static void main(String... args){

        String[][] arr2 = new String[5][5]; 
        for (final String[] obj : arr2)
        {
            int value = obj.length;
            for (final String str : obj)
                System.out.println(str.length() +" " + value); 
        }
    }
}
```

after compiling and then again decompiling I got this.

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_114.
 */
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Test1 {
    public static /* varargs */ void main(String ... arrstring) {
        String[][] arrstring2;
        for (String[] arrstring3 : arrstring2 = new String[5][5]) {
            int n = arrstring3.length;  //Assignment will take place M times only.
            //this will calculate M times only. So, it will definitely faster than above. 
            for (String string : arrstring3) { 
                System.out.println("" + string.length() + " " + n);
               //here n is calculate M times but can be printed M*N times.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

surprising as it may seems try:

```
for (final Bar a : bars) {
    innerLoop(a, foos);
}

 private final innerLoop(Bar a, Collection<Foo> foos) {
    for (final Foo f : foos) {
        doSomethingWith(f.foo(), a.bar());
 }
```

just a small tweak, give it a try

Comment: What do you hope to gain by this? Btw. you've also got a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

After seeing comments and having to answer on them, I realized that even if the compiler would dive into understanding `a.bar()`'s code, it would be impossible to guarentee that `a.bar()` result would not change in a multi-threaded enviroment such as it is in java, also, in conjuction with Reflection if `bar` is a member field it can change through reflections and the compiler wouldnt know that in advance which can cause a simple `return bar;` to be unpredictable.

So currently, it seems rational to me to keep bothering to use that optimization in my code.

Comment: "guarentee that `a.bar()` result would not change in a multi-threaded enviroment" - unless the method contains some synchronization or friends (like `volatile`), the compiler is free to ignore other threads. Without synchronization, the JMM guarantees no visibility of changes made by other threads and neither the HW guarantees anything (think per core caches). +++ That said, it might be a useful optimization on Android, which is not as smart as server class JVM.

Comment: Note that the change to the member could occur between iterations on foos objects, volatile will not help in this case and synchronization may help only if its done right. i find it hard to believe that a compiler could analyse the correctness of your synchronization in all cases...

Comment: What if `a.bar()` is a `final` method that returns a `final` field?

Comment: @shmosel A method being final is irrelevant here. Reading of a final field is guaranteed to see its value. Changing a value of a final field via reflection is possible, but you lose the guarantee. +++ My point is that the compiler may inline the method and 1. if it's simple enough and 2. contains neither synchronization nor friends, then it may avoid redundant loads.

Comment: @OfekRon The compiler surely doesn't care about whether you did your synchronization right. First, it looks whether it can inline a method, If not, then it's done with it. Otherwise, it looks for means of synchronization. If there are *any*, then it must provide the visibility guarantees. Otherwise, it's free to avoid redundant loads.

Comment: @maaartinus the method (or class) would need to be `final` to allow it to be safely inlined, otherwise it may have been overridden. About the `final` field, you're probably right that as long as there are no memory consistency guarantees the JVM/compiler can do what it wants.

Comment: @shmosel That's just not true. It's enough when there's just a single implementation *at the moment*. If another class gets loaded and things change, the method doing the now invalid optimizations gets [deoptimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optimization#Deoptimization), executed by the interpreter and (unless not used much) finally compiled again. +++ On Android, things are very different, optimizations were not that powerfull, and now, [AOT compilation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/274673/14167) gets used.